# Jquery mobile 1.4.2 - dynamically active check box radio

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am currently workking with Jquery 1.4.2 on a mobile app. I have a list of questions.As soon as a user taps on item, a popup with its response is diplayed. each response is a checkbox radio. Responses are inside a fieldset with data-role=control group.

If a user has already respond to the question, i want to activate the checkbox radio, else just nothing. I wrote some code, It works well under desktop's browsers, but it does not work with mobile's browser. I do not know why. Actually, during few milliseconds, the activate checkbox radio is well displayed (it is checked), then that switches to an other response (so an other checkbox radio). I do not know why I get this behavior ???

My code when a listitem is clicked/tapped. It allows to load dynamically question's response in a popup.

```
var fieldset = $("#contentResponse");
fieldset.empty();
var radioSurvey="";

for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
    var label="";
    if(status == 'active'){

        if(userHasAlreadyAnswered != "null" && userHasAlreadyAnswered == response[i].RESPONSE_ID){
            console.log("checked ...");
            radiochecked = "#"+response[i].RESPONSE_ID;
            label = '<label>' + '<input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radioSurvey" value="'+question_id+'_'+response[i].RESPONSE_ID+'_'+survey_id+'" id="'+response[i].RESPONSE_ID+'"/>' + response[i].RESPONSE_TEXT+'</label>';
        }else{
            console.log("no checked ...");
            label = '<label>' + '<input type="radio" name="radioSurvey" value="'+question_id+'_'+response[i].RESPONSE_ID+'_'+survey_id+'" id="'+response[i].RESPONSE_ID+'"/>' + response[i].RESPONSE_TEXT+'</label>';
        }
    }

    radioSurvey += label;
}

fieldset.html(radioSurvey);
fieldset.trigger("create");

if(status == 'completed' || status == 'published'){
    $('#sendSurveyButton').hide();
}else{
    $('#sendSurveyButton').show();
}

$("#popupSurveyList").popup("open");
```

EDIT : I saw an overriding from JQM thanks to google developer console.Apparently, JQM append automatically some classes (it is not my code) for label tag, especially the class ui-radio-on !! finally, it is not the first but a random checkbox radio which is checked !

How to resolve this ?

Comment: For jQM 1.4.2 you can call fieldset.enhanceWithin(); instead of  fieldset.trigger("create"); If you still have the issue, you could try placing this line after the popup('open') to see if it is a timing issue of some sort...

Comment: I made an EDIT, could you take a look ?

Comment: you could use the jQM api: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5QnC8/

Comment: yes, I did it. I replace all my code with the sample, but the checkbox radio switched its states. An other one is checked. It is always the class "ui-radio-on which" is added from a mobile web browser. From a laptop's web browser, it works fine.

Comment: by debugging the JS code, my code is good. When I follow the popup, I enter in the jquery.js and it is at this moment that my code is "overidded" !!

Comment: and I use jquery mobile 1.4.2 with jquery 2.1.0